# How to fix expired client cert in docker-machine

Tags: docker, docker-machine

Doing a `docker-machine ls` a got the unexpected `Unable to query docker version: Get https://x.x.x.x:2376/v1.15/version: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid` for every machine.

I hadn't done anything recently.  Looking on SO, I tried some common culprits, VPN, virus, weird clock issues, etc.  None of that applied.  How can I fix make them useable again (via the `docker-machine` interface)?

Using Docker for Mac, 17.12.0-ce-49

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Update** - as I commented on 2/14/2018, this is now part of docker-machine.
Try: `docker-machine regenerate-certs --client-certs`

Historical answer below:

---

First, `docker-machine regenerate-certs` does NOT regenerate the client certificate(s).

After poking around with `openssl` I discovered that it was actually the client certificate that had expired.  Verify:

`openssl x509 -in ~/.docker/machine/certs/cert.pem -text | grep "Not After"`

I tried recreating the certs *in situ* with the same `ca.pem` but it didn't work out (for me).  I'm guessing it would have eventually worked, given a lot more time and trial and error.

What eventually worked was backing up the whole dir, creating a dummy throwaway machine (to force docker-machine to create new certs), moving configs, ssh keys, and server certificates (**not** client certificates), then issuing a regenerate for each machine.  NB, it's disruptive and painful.  As the warning shows, `docker-machine regenerate-certs` will restart docker on the target machine.  Though it's too late for me, I would like to see a better answer.

The process looks something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/.docker || exit
cp -R machine machine.bak
rm -rf machine
docker-machine create deleteme
docker-machine rm -rf deleteme
cd machine/machines || exit

for m in $(~/.docker/machine.bak/machines)
do
    cp -R "../../machine.bak/machines/$m" .
    rm "$m/cert.pem"
    rm "$m/key.pem"
    cp certs/cert.pem "$m"
    cp certs/key.pem "$m"
    docker-machine regenerate-certs -f
done
```

Comment: This was fixed in `docker-machine` master today, and should be useable as `docker-machine --regenerate-certs --client-certs` when the release is out. https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4397

Comment: why cp & rm if you can simply do mv? :)

Comment: Ha I don't remember why I did it that way.  Maybe I was trying to do it safely at first?  Or there might have been a good reason.  I'm glad it helped anyway!

Comment: This wonderful suggestion worked for me! If only the error message had had the correct suggestion: ` Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: There was an error validating  certificates for host  "192.168.99.100:2376": x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid  You can attempt to regenerate them using 'docker-machine regenerate-certs [name]'.`

Answer (score 22):

Try:

```
docker-machine regenerate-certs --client-certs <machine name>
```

The `--client-certs` is important.

Note:

The validity can be inspected by running:

```
openssl x509 -in ~/.docker/machine/certs/cert.pem -text -noout | less
```

The result is something like:

```
 Certificate:
     Data:
     ...
     Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         ...
         Validity
             Not Before: Mar 12 09:03:00 2018 GMT
             Not After : Feb 24 09:03:00 2021 GMT
     ...
```

Comment: I just saw that this was also commented above. I still believe that the validity inspection adds value.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to solve my problem with the above solutions. So I just removed my machines and the corresponding folder with the certs and I was able to correctly create my machine:

```sh
docker-machine rm -y $(docker-machine ls -q)
rm -rf ~/.docker/machine
```