# Kubernetes on Docker Desktop fails to launch after kube-apiserver certificate expiry

Tags: kubernetes, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop, kube-apiserver

Issue type: Kubernetes on Docker Desktop stopped working due to expired kuber-apiserver certificates

OS Version/build: Windows 10 version - 1909 and OS Build - 18363

App version: Docker Desktop 3.03

Steps to reproduce:

1. Install Docker Desktop
2. Enable Kubernetes
3. Change the Windows PC time to ahead by 1 year
4. Kubernetes cluster will stop working saying the kube-apiserver certificates are expired
5. The applications/workloads deployed on the Kubernetes cluster will also stop working.

As Kubernetes certificates are issued for 1 year; after the 1 year time period the certificates are expired and this will break Kubernetes.

[certificate snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaaR2.png)

Need help:
Requesting Information on how to renew the kube-apiserver certificates without affecting the Kubernetes and the installed application

Comment: What exact error are you getting from logs ?

Comment: when I run any kubectl command I get the following output: Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48797261/how-to-fix-expired-client-cert-in-docker-machine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35289802/docker-pull-error-x509-certificate-has-expired-or-is-not-yet-valid

Comment: @Malgorzata Thank you for the pointer. But the above thread is about docker-machine. In my case the issue is kube-apiserver certificates which are issued by kubernetes.

Comment: " If you are running Docker on Windows Server, or Docker Desktop for Windows with Windows containers, the system default certificates are only used when no custom root certificates are configured." https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/certificates/#understand-the-configuration In releases I am not seeing version 3.03 can you upgrade docker-desktop version ? https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/#automatic-updates

Answer (score 1):

I also had the issue showing in the etcd logs:

```
{"level":"warn","ts":"2023-02-14T11:47:26.260Z","caller":"embed/config_logging.go:169","msg":"rejected connection","remote-addr":"192.168.65.4:34996","server-name":"","error":"tls: failed to verify client certificate: x509: certificate has expired or is not yet valid: current time 2023-02-14T11:47:26Z is after 2023-02-03T12:24:57Z"}
```

I found the answer for windows here:
https://forums.docker.com/t/kubernetes-on-docker-desktop-fails-to-launch-after-kube-apiserver-certificate-expiry/106570/2

on Mac OS, the path is `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker`. delete or backup the pki folder and restart docker. kubernetes should come back